# How to set GPU in visual studio / OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, nvidia

I'm using a Surface Book 2 and visual studio. I'm trying to make an OpenGL application and I noticed that it is defaulting to the integrated intel GPU rather than the discrete NVIDIA GPU that is also on the laptop.

I know that I can use the NVIDIA control panel to set the NVIDIA GPU as the default, but the base setting is to "let the application choose" (I understand that the purpose of this setting is to save battery when the better GPU is not needed). I am trying to find a way that I can choose the GPU in my application without manually changing settings in the NVIDIA control panel.

I looked around and it sounds like OpenGL does not support any methods choosing between different GPUs (which is very surprising to me). Is there any way that I can select which GPU I want without using a different API and without changing the settings in the NVIDIA control panel?

Answer (score 0):

Find the executable generated by Visual Studio, and set your GPU for it.

Comment: That worked (I thought it would get overwritten each time I recompiled it, but it still works). However, if I were trying to make this app portable, I wouldn't want to have to manually set this up on each computer I put the app on. Is there not a way to set it up programmatically?